# strings with the arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

hello i have an struct like this:

```
struct Student
{
string name,lettergrade;
int stdnumber,*examgrades;
double  avarege;
};
```

I have to make a programme which it calculates student's avarege and letter grades.

I have to use this functions:

```
void getdata();
double calcgrades();
void show();
void erase();
```

I have to ask user the total number of students and total number of exams. then i have to allocate the necessary memory spaces. (with dynamic allocation)

The output screen must be like this:

```
Enter the number of students: 2
Enter the number of exams: 2
1. student's name: michael
1. student's school number: 5000
1. student's 1. exam grade: 50
1. student's 2. exam grade: 40
The avarege of this student is: 45 Letter grade: F
2. student's name: [b]mary[/b]
2. student's school number: 6000
2. student's 1. exam grade: 70
2. student's 2. exam grade: 80
The avarege of this student is: 75 Letter grade: B
```

My problem is, i cant allocate it for the string variables, like student name and letter grade... (in the getdata function)

Letter grades are  A: 85-100, B:75-84, C:65-74, D:50-64,F:0-49  over 100 points.

Can anyone has any idea about this problem?

EDIT:

```
void getdata()
{
    int i,j;
    i=0;j=0;
    int stdnumber;
    int examnumber;
    cout<<"How many students..."<<endl;
    cin>>stdnumber;
    Student k[stdnumber];
    cout<<"How many exams...."<<endl;
    cin>>examnumber;
    for (i=0;i<stdnumber;i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<". student's name: "<<endl;
        cin>>k[i].name;
        cout<<i+1<<". student's school number: "<<endl;
        cin>>k[i].stdnumber;
        for (j=0;j<examnumber;j++)
        {
            cout<<i+1<<". student's "<<j+1<<". exam grade: "<<endl;
            cin>>k[i]->examgrades; //The error is here: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Student'|

        }
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to tell you is my problem is with the pointers. I dont know how can I allocate the enough memory space for the exam grades?

Comment: What is your code so far? Where are you encountering problems?

Comment: "I have to make" is this homework? Haven't they told you then a few tools  already from which you could chose?

Comment: Sure let's close this as not constructive. </sarcasm> @WhoCares Can you use `std::vector`?

Comment: Also, how is `getdata` supposed to return the data?

Comment: C++ does not have variable length arrays and so `Student k[stdnumber];`
 is not valid C++. This is a common newbie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `k` is an array of `Student`, not an array of `Student*`. So you need to use `.` instead of  `->`. That's why you get that error. Another issue with that code is that you're using a non-constant value for the array size, which is not allowed in C++.

For dynamic allocation, the easiest solution would be to use `std::vector`. That takes care of both allocation and the deallocation, without extra care.

Given that this is homework, if for some reason you are not allowed to use `std::vector` you will need to use `new[]` and `delete[]`.

If for some incredibly stupid reason you cannot use `new[]` and `delete[]` you'll need to use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: should also add that C++ does not allow variable length arrays yet.

Comment: I think it is not in the standard but supported by most compilers. It is there in C99

Comment: @balki: it isn't there in C++. Try compiling it in C++ mode.

Comment: It is in GCC but not other major compilers, such as Visual Studio.

Comment: Even in GCC, it gives "ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'v' [-Wvla]" if you compile in C++ mode.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to allocate any `string` (although there would be no
problems doing so if you did).  You have to allocate `Student`.  In C++,
the normal way of allocating an array of `Student` would be:

```
std::vector <Student> students( studentCount );
```

Similarly, the normal way of allocating an array of `int` would be:

```
std::vector <int> examgrades( examCount );
```

This would require changing the structure of `Student` to something
like:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string         name;
    std::string         letterGrade;
    int                 studentNumber;
    std::vector <int>   examGrades;
    double              average;

    Student( int examCount ) : examGrades( examCount ) {}
};
```

If you use a pointer for `Student::examGrades`, there is no way to write
the code correctly in C++ without providing both a constructor and a
destructor for `Student`.  If you do the above, once you've entered the
number of students and the number of exams, all that you have to do is:

```
std::vector <Student> students( studentCount, Student( examCount ) );
```

and everything necessary will have been allocated.  Alternatively, you
initialize the vector empty, and loop over the input, using `push_back`
to add the fully initialized students.  (This is actually a much better
solution, since it prevents any student from ever existing without being
correctly initialized.)

If your professor is trying to teach some other solution, using pointers
(there should be no pointers in this program), then I'd recommend you
change professors (and if possible, get this one fired for
incompetence).  Until then, however, you can always do

```
Student* students = new Student[studentCount];
for ( int i = 0; i != studentCount; ++ i )
    students[i].examGrades = new int[examCount];
```

Of course, `getData` will have to return some sort of a `struct`, since
it has to return the pointer to the `Student`s, plus the `studentCount`
and the `examCount`.  And somewhere, you'll have to write code to delete
all of this memory.  (And if you really want to do it correctly, you'll
have to wrap most code in a lot of `try ... catch` blocks, to correctly
free the memory if there is an exception.  `std::vector` takes care of
the allocation, the deletes, and all of the exception handling for you.)